# TypeScript: custom class extending Array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm having some troubles with a custom class extending Array. I basically just want to add a few helper methods on the Array class, here I'm adding a `logMe` method, with a prefix to the array.

```
class AAA extends Array {
  _prefix: string;

  constructor(prefix: string, values: number[]) {
    console.log('AAA contructor', values);

    // Use hack
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673043/extending-array-from-typescript
    super();
    this.push(...values);

    this._prefix = prefix;
  }

  logMe() {
    console.log('The prefix is:', this._prefix);
    console.log('The values are:');
    this.map(x => x * 2).forEach(console.log);
  }
}
```

And here's my test:

```
const a = new AAA('PREFIX-A', [1, 2, 3]);
a.logMe();
```

Expected result:

```
AAA contructor [ 1, 2, 3 ]
The prefix is: PREFIX-A
The values are: 1, 2, 3
```

Actual result:

```
AAA contructor [ 1, 2, 3 ]
The prefix is: PREFIX-A
AAA contructor undefined

/Users/amaurymartiny/Workspaces/test-array/a.ts:7
    this.push(...values);
         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of this.push
    at new AAA (/Users/amaurymartiny/Workspaces/test-array/a.ts:7:10)
    at AAA.map (<anonymous>)
    at AAA.logMe (/Users/amaurymartiny/Workspaces/test-array/a.ts:13:41)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/amaurymartiny/Workspaces/test-array/a.ts:18:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/amaurymartiny/Workspaces/test-array/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/Users/amaurymartiny/Workspaces/test-array/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
```

This is quite strange to me, why is the constructor called again when I call `this.map`?

TypeScript 3.1.3. NodeJS 10.12.0. I already implemented [this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673043/extending-array-from-typescript).

Comment: Are you intending to call the native `map` function on `Array`? Doesn't that return a new array?

Comment: You're logging the call the `console.log` didn't you mean to write `console.log('The values are:', this.join(", "))`

Comment: @FrankModica Yes, I'm intending to call the native map. Yes, that returns a new Array, so should call the constructor of Array, not the one of `AAA`.

Comment: @Motti Fixed. I actually want the child class to use the `map` method,

Comment: Oh you're right, interesting!

Comment: @amaurymartiny note that `map` sends three parameters to the function it's called with, (value, index, original-array) so you won't get your _expected_ result. (This is by the way and doesn't relate to the basis of your question).

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It worked for me.

```
class Collection extends Array<xxx> {    
   constructor(documents: Array<xxx> | number) {
      if(documents instanceof Array) super(...documents);
      else super(documents);
      Object.setPrototypeOf(this, Object.create(Collection.prototype));
   }      
   public get aMethodUsingMapAsExample(): string[] {
      // this.map invokes the constructor with the length passed in as argument
      var types = this.map(e => e.documentType);
      types = types.sort();
      return types;
   }  
}
```

**explanation**: native array constructor has **2 overloads**. You have to support both of them in your extending class. This is because this.map, behind the scenes, creates a new array, thereby invoking the constructor with the length of the array.

- ArrayConstructor(...items: any[]): Here you **must call the spread** operator for the array to be constructed correctly
- ArrayConstructor(arrayLength: number). Calling the spread operator on object of type number will *throw an exception*.

Comment: there is an exception if you pass an array that contains one single element of type number it will consider the single element as a the length of the array solution if (arr instanceof Array) {
      if (arr.length == 1) {
        super();
        this.push(arr[0]);
      } else {
        super(...arr);
      }
    }